# Is there anything one can do if traceroute shows issues along the path?

Tags: networking, dns, ping, troubleshooting, traceroute

Since few days I cannot reach anymore a site: [assist.zoho.com](http://assist.zoho.com) (or [assist.zoho.eu](http://assist.zoho.eu)).

Here the output of `traceroute`:

```
$ traceroute -I assist.zoho.com
traceroute to assist.zoho.com (136.143.191.95), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  fritz.box (192.168.1.1)  1.807 ms  1.799 ms  1.797 ms
 2  host5-41-98-79.dynamic.ehiweb.it (79.98.41.5)  9.216 ms  9.214 ms  9.213 ms
 3  host224-41-98-79.dynamic.ehiweb.it (79.98.41.224)  9.211 ms  9.209 ms  9.207 ms
 4  10-229-157-185.fibertelecom.it (185.157.229.10)  13.174 ms  13.173 ms  13.172 ms
 5  81-228-157-185.fibertelecom.it (185.157.228.81)  13.169 ms  13.168 ms  13.166 ms
 6  * * *
 7  ae3.cs1.cdg11.fr.zip.zayo.com (64.125.27.14)  165.465 ms  165.428 ms  165.420 ms
 8  ae0.cs1.cdg12.fr.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.84)  165.416 ms  165.414 ms  165.411 ms
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * ae3.cs3.ord2.us.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.209)  166.201 ms
12  ae2.cs1.sea1.us.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.26)  164.873 ms  164.870 ms  164.868 ms
13  ae28.mpr2.sea1.us.zip.zayo.com (64.125.29.103)  164.864 ms  164.410 ms  164.403 ms
14  64.124.135.82.idia-291213-003-zyo.zip.zayo.com (64.124.135.82)  167.050 ms  167.048 ms  167.873 ms
15  204.141.42.14 (204.141.42.14)  176.735 ms  176.727 ms  174.087 ms
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

and:

```
$ traceroute -I assist.zoho.eu
traceroute to assist.zoho.eu (213.244.146.83), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  fritz.box (192.168.1.1)  1.674 ms  1.666 ms  1.664 ms
 2  host5-41-98-79.dynamic.ehiweb.it (79.98.41.5)  9.285 ms  9.285 ms  9.283 ms
 3  host224-41-98-79.dynamic.ehiweb.it (79.98.41.224)  9.281 ms  9.280 ms  9.278 ms
 4  10-229-157-185.fibertelecom.it (185.157.229.10)  30.519 ms  30.519 ms  31.318 ms
 5  4-1-6-101.bear1.milan2.level3.net (213.249.105.25)  10.125 ms  10.124 ms  10.123 ms
 6  ae2-3220.msr3.frankfurt1.level3.net (4.69.167.66)  18.367 ms  18.710 ms  18.704 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

It isn't an issue about DNS because it is resolved and running the above tests with the IP leads to the same output.
The servers does not answer to ping requests, by the way.

That said, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Do you happen to have a (couple of) traceroute(s) from when it worked? Without knowing where zoho.com/zoho.eu should be (network wise) it's impossible to say what those show. But in any case: What you see lines 6,9-11 in the first output only shows the presence of routers that don't respond to the packages your traceroute sends, but as there are routers responding further along the path that's not a problem.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity unfortunately not. Because it worked I didn't trace it...

Comment: `Traceroute` in such circumstances is pointless. Many places will firewall off icmp & unknown udp packets. You are far better off with trying `tcptraceroute`, but read the man page first.

Comment: @Mark : I'm not surprised but, as I said, it makes it that much harder to help you. What I can suggest is to contact zoho.com's support - their website is up and there is a link to support.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity I've already did, but I want to better understand how it works under the hood. They say all is working fine from their side, btw.